# Get memory used by the GPU in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I get the RAM memory used by the GPU (video) in iOS?

I am able to get the following memory stats: **active_count**, **inactive_count**, **wire_count**, **free_count**, but not the video used memory.

Comment: Hi have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is the method I use to obtain the memory usage:

```
#import <mach/mach_host.h>

NSDictionary* getMemoryState (){

    mach_port_t host_port;
    mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
    vm_size_t pagesize;

    host_port = mach_host_self();
    host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

    vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;

    if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");
    }

    /* Stats in bytes */
    natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                          vm_stat.inactive_count +
                          vm_stat.wire_count) *  (unsigned int) pagesize;

    natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * (unsigned int)pagesize;
    natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;

    //NSLog(@"used: %u free: %u total: %u active: %u video: %u", mem_used / 1024 /1024, mem_free / 1024 /1024, mem_total / 1024 /1024, vm_stat.active_count, 999 - (mem_total / 1024 /1024));

    NSMutableDictionary *dictWithMemoryStats = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:mem_total / 1024 / 1024] , @"total",
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:mem_used / 1024 / 1024], @"used",
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:mem_free / 1024 / 1024], @"free",
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:((vm_stat.active_count *  (unsigned int) pagesize) / 1024 / 1024)], @"active",
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:(vm_stat.inactive_count  *  (unsigned int) pagesize) / 1024 /1014], @"inactive",
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:(vm_stat.wire_count  *  (unsigned int) pagesize) / 1024/ 1024], @"wire",
                                                nil];

    return dictWithMemoryStats;

}
```

Then, to obtain the memory occupied by the GPU you must get the Total RAM memory of the device from which you subtract the total memory obtained from the method above.

```
let dictWithRamInfi: NSDictionary = getMemoryState()
let proInfo = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()

let totalRam: UInt64 = ((proInfo.physicalMemory / 1024) / 1024)
let totalActiveRam: UInt64 = UInt64(dictWithRamInfi["total"]!.unsignedLongLongValue)

let videoRam = totalRam - totalActiveRam
```